# Energy electrostatic of a charged sphere

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, potential-energy

I am reading the Feynman books.
In 8.1, we have shown that the energy of a charged sphere of radius $a$ is
$$U = \frac{4\pi\rho^2a^5}{15\epsilon_0}.$$

I tried to get this result using the following formula
$$U=\frac{\epsilon_0}{2}\iiint E^2\,dV.$$
Through Gauss theorem, we can write that for $r < a$,
$$E=\frac{Q_{int}}{S\cdot\epsilon_0}=\frac{\rho r}{3 \epsilon_0}.$$
So I tried to integrate it to get the energy.
First, we can say that $dV = 4\pi r^2\,dr$

Thus we got:
$$U=\frac{\epsilon_0}{2}\int_0^a \left(\frac{\rho r}{3\epsilon_0}\right)^2 4\pi r^2\,dr $$
$$U=\frac{4\pi\rho^2a^5}{45 \epsilon_0}$$

I got a result 3 times too small and I don't understand why. If someone can explain to me where am I wrong :).

EDIT:
Taking account of the comment of @mmesser314, I tried to integrate from infinity to a.
Now, since $r>a$, $E=\frac{a^3\rho}{3\epsilon_0 r^2}.$

Integrating it from $\infty$ to $a$ gives me $$U=\frac{2\pi\rho^2a^5}{9 \epsilon_0}.$$

Comment: Charges have no potential energy when spread out. Instead of $\int_0^a$, try $\int_{\infty}^a$.

Comment: @mmesser314 I think I did not understand exactly what you mean by charges have no potential energy when spread out. I made an edit using your recommendations for the integral, however, I am still not getting the $\frac{1}{15}$ factor...

Comment: The integration for this formula is of ALL space. Use gauss theorem to find the E field inside the sphere and integrate from r=0 and r= a, then use gauss theorem to find the E field outside of the sphere. And integrate that from r= a to infinity

Comment: I'm pretty sure mmesser thinks that you are trying to find the potential from a spherical shell. From which the potential inside doesn't vary,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, you have lost a factor of $2$ for the energy inside the sphere. It is:
$$
\frac{2 \pi \rho^2 a^5}{45 \epsilon_0}
$$

Secondly, the energy on a charged sphere involves the energy of the field in the **whole** space. You have missed the contribution to energy that comes from outside:
$$
\frac{\epsilon_0}{2} \int_{a}^{\infty} \left(\frac{\rho a^3}{3 \epsilon_0 r^2}\right)^{2} 4 \pi r^2 dr =
\frac{2 \pi \rho^2 a^6}{9 \epsilon_0} \int_{a}^{\infty} \frac{dr}{r^2} = \frac{2 \pi \rho^2 a^5}{9 \epsilon_0}
$$
In total:
$$
\frac{2 \pi \rho^2 a^5}{45 \epsilon_0} + \frac{2 \pi \rho^2 a^5}{9 \epsilon_0} = 
\frac{12 \pi \rho^2 a^5}{45 \epsilon_0} = \frac{4 \pi \rho^2 a^5}{15 \epsilon_0}
$$